# Retrieving an injected build parameter in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm specifically working on the example below, but I'm guessing the question is a bit more general.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin
States the following build parameters, are injected into the job

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo env.pmt_content
                echo ${pmt_content}
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The above methods don't seem to work for me:

How is it possible to retrieve an injected build parameter in a pipeline job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [pipeline-plugin tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#build-parameters), you can use `params` to access the job's build parameters.

```
    print params.pmt_content 
    print "Content is ${params.pmt_content}"
```